# Extending a Panel Within a Panel Vertically

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working on an application using the Swing GUI widget in Java and am having issues with stretching panels vertically within a panel. My main panel is using the BorderLayout and the problem is in the Center Region. I am using a Panel with a BoxLayout.X_AXIS and inside of it additional Panels with a BoxLayout.Y_AXIS are inserted. I am unable to stretch it vertically from top to bottom. I also want the contents to start from the top to the bottom. I have tried using the GridLayout and it does exactly what I want, however I am constrained width wise because all of the columns are equivalent size and I want some panels to have a smaller width. I have looked at the API, tutorials, and searched Googled for an answer. Any help would be great!

Attached are the code and the screenshot with the layouts.
[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Colors
{
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main (String[] args){
    Colors gui = new Colors();
    gui.start();
}

public void start(){
    frame = new JFrame("Words");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,8));
    center();
    east();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void center(){
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    //centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,0));
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    JLabel oneLabel,twoLabel,threeLabel;

    JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
    panelOne.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelOne,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelOne.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    oneLabel = new JLabel("  First Label First Column  ");
    panelOne.add(oneLabel);
    twoLabel = new JLabel("  Second Label First Column  ");
    panelOne.add(twoLabel);
    threeLabel = new JLabel("  Third Label First Column  ");
    panelOne.add(threeLabel);
    centerPanel.add(panelOne);

    JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();
    panelTwo.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelTwo,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelTwo.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    oneLabel = new JLabel("  10  ");
    panelTwo.add(oneLabel);
    twoLabel = new JLabel("  20  ");
    panelTwo.add(twoLabel);
    threeLabel = new JLabel("  30  ");
    panelTwo.add(threeLabel);
    centerPanel.add(panelTwo);

    JPanel panelThree = new JPanel();
    panelThree.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelThree,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelThree.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    oneLabel = new JLabel("  10  ");
    panelThree.add(oneLabel);
    twoLabel = new JLabel("  20  ");
    panelThree.add(twoLabel);
    threeLabel = new JLabel("  30  ");
    panelThree.add(threeLabel);
    centerPanel.add(panelThree);

    contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private void east(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,150));
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
    labelPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    labelPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(26,24));
    panel.add(labelPanel);

    labelPanel = new JPanel();
    labelPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    labelPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(26,24));
    panel.add(labelPanel);

    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
}      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using the GridLayout and it does exactly what I want, however I am constrained width wise because all of the columns are equivalent size and I want some panels to have a smaller width

You can try using the `GridBagLayout`. Each column will be the width of the largest component in the column.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and working examples.

Another option might be to use a `JTable`. A JTable allows you to display data in a row/column format. The above tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Tables`.